# DialogFragment reappears after activity recreate() even after dismissing it

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am showing one DialogFragment inside an activity. Now when I call recreate from the activity (trying to reproduce kill on low memory issue) I want to dismiss the dialog. So I tried calling  dismissAllowingStateLoss() and removing fragment from the onStop of the fragment. But even after that I see onCreateDialog() of DialogFragment getting called.

My objective is to cancel the dissmiss the DialogFragment when acitvity recreates, but for me dialog is always reappearing, Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is to do it from parent activity but it looks like in your case parent activity have no control on you dialog fragment, right?
So your DialogFragment is more like a "Toast" dialog with a timer or with an OK button, correct?

Comment: Yes, this dialog fragment appears like a toast with button.